# Cookie management in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

### How do I configure cookie management in the Quarkus rest client?

I am building a client to an API that sets a session cookie on login and then uses that session cookie for auth - a pretty standard stateful API.

It seems that with default behaviour with `@RegisterRestClient` does not preserve cookies between requests.

Having a dig, it seems that `ResteasyClientBuilderImpl` has a field `cookieManagementEnabled` which is `false` by default. This then disables cookies in `ClientHttpEngineBuilder43` by default too.

I also found that if you use the async engine (`useAsyncHttpEngine`) this sync engine builder is not used and cookie management is also enabled.

The only way I found to configure the `ResteasyClientBuilder` underlying the `RestClientBuilder` was to use a `RestClientBuilderListener`. However, the plot thickens here.

There is a method in `RestClientBuilder` - [`property(String name, Object value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html#property-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) - that, in the case of [`Quarkus at least`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/resteasy-classic/rest-client/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/restclient/runtime/QuarkusRestClientBuilder.java) will delegate to the underlying `ResteasyClientBuilder`

```java
if (name.startsWith(RESTEASY_PROPERTY_PREFIX)) {
    // Makes it possible to configure some of the ResteasyClientBuilder delegate properties
```

However, a few lines down

```java
Method builderMethod = Arrays.stream(ResteasyClientBuilder.class.getMethods())
  .filter(m -> builderMethodName.equals(m.getName()) && m.getParameterTypes().length >= 1)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null);
```

i.e. it will only allows for non-nullary methods to be called. And to enable cookie management I need to call [`enableCookieManagement`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html#enableCookieManagement--) - which has no arguments.

So, the only way I have found to enable cookie management is:

```kotlin
class CookieConfigBuilderListener : RestClientBuilderListener {
    override fun onNewBuilder(builder: RestClientBuilder) {
        val builderImpl = builder as QuarkusRestClientBuilder
        val delegateField = QuarkusRestClientBuilder::class.java.getDeclaredField("builderDelegate")
        delegateField.isAccessible = true
        val resteasyBuilder = delegateField.get(builderImpl) as ResteasyClientBuilder
        resteasyBuilder.enableCookieManagement()
    }
}
```

This is obviously far from ideal, not least because it uses reflection in a GraalVM native image setting and therefore will likely also require me to enable reflection on `QuarkusRestClientBuilder`.

So, back to the original question, how do I enable cookie management in the Quarkus rest client?

Comment: I think the best is to open a feature request on the Quarkus Github repo as it seems to be a non-available setting.
Using relfection to hack into Quarkus internal is a bad idea because they can change from one release to another without further notice.